# webpack multiple entry points

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working on an Angular project using webpack and I have set two different entry points

```
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': ['./src/main.ts', './src/counter.ts']   },
```

Main and Counter are two modules and then when I put in my index.html `<counter></counter>`  and `<app-root></app-root>`, it works

But after exporting the app with `npm run build --prod` command on the production environment only works app-root not counter. any clue about this weird behaviour?

Thanks!